# How to get the 'place' of a Number in Java (eg. tens, thousands, etc)

Tags: java

How can I determine the number places of a number and determine the number of a loop to run?

For example, if i have an array `int[] a= {123,342,122,333,9909}` and `int max = a.getMax()` we get the value 9909. I want to get the *number place value* of 9909, which is the thousand-th place.

For example...

```
(number place value,number of loop to run)

(one,1 time)
(tenth,2 time)
(hundred,3 time)
(thousand,4 time)
(ten thousand,5 time)
(hundred thousand,6 time)
```

Here is my code, however it fails when it meets a zero between an integer...

```
public static int getMax(int[] t,int n){
     int maximum = t[0];   // first value of the array
     int index = 0;
     int div=1;
     int numSpace=0;
     int valueTester=34;
     boolean done=false;

     for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
       if (t[i] > maximum) {
         maximum = t[i];   // maximum
         index = i; // comparing index
       }  
     }

     while(done==false){
         if (valueTester==0){
             done=true;
             }
          else{
            valueTester=(maximum / div) % 10;
            div=div*10;
            numSpace++;
            }
        }

     return numSpace;
     }

  }
```

Comment: You could at least attempt to format your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use logarithms.

```
    double[] values = {4, 77, 234, 4563, 13467, 635789};
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        double tenthPower = Math.floor(Math.log10(values[i]));
        double place = Math.pow(10, tenthPower);
        System.out.println(place);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks there. i just need the double tenthPower = Math.floor(Math.log10(values[i]));

Comment: Log isn't defined for negative numbers, So this solution won't work for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the place of the number, you can convert the integer to a String, and get the length of it.

For example...

```
int[] a= {123,342,122,333,9909};
int maxNumber = a.getMax(); // will return '9909'
int numberPlace = (new Integer(maxNumber)).toString().length; // will return '4'
```

Then you need to get an English value for the place, such as...

```
String[] placeNames = new String[]{"zero","ones","tens","hundreds","thousands"};
String placeString = placeNames[numberPlace]; // will return "thousands"
```

Is this all that you're asking? I'm not sure if I understand the rest of your question

Comment: sorry i post my code abit late... but the first part of the code might be helpful.. i will try first.

Comment: is there any way that where you dont have to cast the int to string then string to integer ?

Comment: Thats not really what is happening. You need it to be a `String` so that you can get the `length()` of it - you can't get the length of an `int`. A shorthand for that line would be `int numberPlace = (""+maxNumber).length;`, but it still does the same thing in the background

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet can be used to get the value of the hundredths element in an integer:

```
public int place(int i) {
    int j=(i/100)%10;
    return j;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int a = 9909;

switch(a)
{
   case a < 10:
     //ones place
     break;
   case a < 100:
     //hundreds place
     break;
   //etc.....
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah this might help if its value small... but in my assignment im dealing with random number which is the biggest possible number in Int value. In that case we will have a lot cases and break. is there any other way>?

Comment: @YuvinNg You didn't mention how large the inputs would be in your question, so I didn't know. For large numbers it would probably be easiest to convert them to a String object, then test its length property.

Comment: @YuvinNg There is never only one way to do something, a String is a simple solution you will find for large numbers `n`. You can also use logarithms to get the digits and save yourself any string conversions.